# php date format inserting wrong date

Tags: php, mysql, epoch

I am confused as to why this piece of code does not convert a date in the UK format 00/00/0000 to mysql date format 0000-00-00. What i get in the db is 1970-01-01. It is in the date format not datetime so it should work? Thanks

```
$destroy = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['destroy']);
$desttempdate=str_replace("-", "/", $destroy); 
$destdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($desttempdate));
```

Comment: default date format of your MySQL is different than your PHP .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few options for you to get it working:

### Something like this for PHP4:

```
function date2timestamp($date,$seperator='/'){
    if($date!=''){
        $dateEx = explode($seperator,$date);
        $date = (strlen($dateEx[2])==2?'20'.$dateEx[2]:$dateEx[2]).'-'.$dateEx[1].'-'.$dateEx[0].' 00:00:00';
    }
    return $date;
}
```

### For PHP5.3 use [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/M/Y', $UK_date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

### Also other options for createFromFormat() in PHP5.2 include:

- [PHP createFromFormat for 5.2 version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3754441/461813)
- [php dateTime::createFromFormat in 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5399075/461813)
- [DateTime::createFromFormat in PHP < 5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312354/461813)

Comment: He is reordering the date just fine with the `date` call. The problem is that `strtotime` returns a bad value.

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` function will return Unix timestamp and `0000-00-00` date does not fit into that - you will just get `0` (zero) instead, which will be converted properly, to `1970-01-01`.

You can do what you want by doing something like that:

```
$destdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['destroy']); // assuming YYYY/MM/DD
$destdate = str_replace('/', '-', $destdate);
if ($destdate != '0000-00-00'){
    $destdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($desttempdate));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing to `strtotime` what it thinks is an invalid date. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) says:

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So what's happening here is that you are passing in a string using the `/` separator, which means that `strtotime` tries to parse it as `m/d/y` instead of `d/m/y`. Either do not do the replace at all if your date is in the european format, or better yet use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` as the docs suggest.

You can check that this is indeed the problem by checking the return value of `strtotime`:

```
$destroy = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['destroy']);
$desttempdate=str_replace("-", "/", $destroy);
var_dump(strtotime($desttempdate));
```

This will output "bool (false)", confirming that `strtotime` fails to parse its input.

**Solution:**

As mentioned above, prefer `DateTime::createFromFormat()`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['destroy']);
$destdate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Otherwise, even though I do not recommend this approach, the simplest way to fix the problem would be simply to skip the `str_replace`:

```
$destdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['destroy']));
```